# Updating grouped data based on date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe that looks like the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2'], 
                   'ID2': ['25', '29', '56', '562', '92', '170'],
                   'Origin': ['2005', '2010', '2020', '1995', '1999', '2007'],
                   'Status' : ['Done', 'Unfinished', 'Done', 'Done', 'Done', 'Unfinished']
                  })
df


+----+-----+--------+------------+
| ID | ID2 | Origin |   Status   |
+----+-----+--------+------------+
|  1 |  25 |   2005 | Done       |
|  1 |  29 |   2010 | Unfinished |
|  1 |  56 |   2020 | Done       |
|  2 | 562 |   1995 | Done       |
|  2 |  92 |   1999 | Done       |
|  2 | 170 |   2007 | Unfinished |
+----+-----+--------+------------+
```

I am trying to separate into groups based on `ID` and update the `Status` column from `Unfinished` to `Done` if there is another row in the same group with a newer `Done` value. Essentially, if the `Unfinished` row is the most recent within the group, then leave the same. If `Unfinished` is *not* the most recent, change to `Done`.

Sample output below:

```
+----+-----+--------+------------+----------------+
| ID | ID2 | Origin |   Status   | Updated_Status |
+----+-----+--------+------------+----------------+
|  1 |  25 |   2005 | Done       |                |
|  1 |  29 |   2010 | Unfinished | Done           |
|  1 |  56 |   2020 | Done       |                |
|  2 | 562 |   1995 | Done       |                |
|  2 |  92 |   1999 | Done       |                |
|  2 | 170 |   2007 | Unfinished |                |
+----+-----+--------+------------+----------------+
```

After I finish `df.groupby('ID')` I know I have to try some variation of
`df.loc[(df['Status'] == 'Unfinished') & (df['Origin'] > today.year)]` but I can't think of the proper logic or syntax to properly adjust this dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can test if shifted values per groups by [`DataFrameGroupBy.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html) are `Done` and also if same row has `Unfinished` - both conditions are chain by `&` for bitwise `AND`, last set values in [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df = df.sort_values(['ID','Origin'])
mask = df.groupby('ID')['Status'].shift(-1).eq('Done') & df['Status'].eq('Unfinished')
df['Updated_Status'] = np.where(mask, 'Done', '')
print (df)
  ID  ID2 Origin      Status Updated_Status
0  1   25   2005        Done               
1  1   29   2010  Unfinished           Done
2  1   56   2020        Done               
3  2  562   1995        Done               
4  2   92   1999        Done               
5  2  170   2007  Unfinished
```

Alternative solution if possible test if last value is `Done` per group is use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
df = df.sort_values(['ID','Origin'])
mask = (df.groupby(['ID'])['Status'].transform('last').eq('Done') & 
        df['Status'].eq('Unfinished'))
df['Updated_Status'] = np.where(mask, 'Done', '')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
# is the value "Done"?
m = df['Status'].eq('Done')
# keep only the True, backfill them per group
# this leaves the terminal "Unfinished" as NaN, which we fill as False
m2 = m.where(m).groupby(df['ID']).bfill().fillna(False)

# we could also use a reverse cummax
# m2 = m[::-1].groupby(df['ID']).cummax()

# boolean indexing
df.loc[m2&~m, 'Updated_Status'] = 'Done'
```

Output:

```
  ID  ID2 Origin      Status Updated_Status
0  1   25   2005        Done            NaN
1  1   29   2010  Unfinished           Done
2  1   56   2020        Done            NaN
3  2  562   1995        Done            NaN
4  2   92   1999        Done            NaN
5  2  170   2007  Unfinished            NaN
```

##### alternative format

Use `df['Updated_Status'] = np.where(m2&~m, 'Done', '')` as last line:

```
  ID  ID2 Origin      Status Updated_Status
0  1   25   2005        Done               
1  1   29   2010  Unfinished           Done
2  1   56   2020        Done               
3  2  562   1995        Done               
4  2   92   1999        Done               
5  2  170   2007  Unfinished
```

Answer (score 1):

Updated_Status = df.groupby('ID').last()['Status'].replace('Unfinished','')

Following is the output upon printing Updated_Status

[image]

Must add this to the dataframe,,

Answer (score 1):

It is as simple as

```
mask = (df.groupby('ID')['Status'].transform('last') == 'Done') & (df.Status == 'Unfinished')
df['Updated_Status'] = np.where(mask, 'Done', np.nan)
```

The last row in each group corresponds to the latest entry. Use that to transform for each `Status`. Then, use the condition for updating the status.